# strtok_s() Why do we need address of a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am back with C++ after 15 years...I just can't remember why we need the address of a pointer. Like in this statement:

```
char *next_token = NULL;
char *pszMozilla = strtok_s(szCopyVariable, "/", &next_token);
```

Is there an assumption that the address of the pointer will represent eventually the start of a list of pointers ?

Comment: Because `strtok_s` shall store a pointer in `next_token`, so it needs its address to know where.

Comment: Okay. I'm new here. I see @DanielFischer post the same answer I did, except he posted 36 seconds before I did. For questions like these, are you supposed to just answer via a comment?

Comment: @RamRajamony If you don't feel like typing a real answer, you can post a quick helpful comment like I did [well, I hope it is helpful]. Then, if nobody posts a full-fledged answer, there is at least some help for the OP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`strtok_s` is a reentrant function, and it needs to store some state somewhere. That state is a pointer to the character one after the last one it processed. (Think about it, that's really all you need to resume tokenizing.)

If a function wants to store an X in a user-provided space, the user needs to provide a pointer to an X, pointing to where the X will go. In our case, X is a "pointer to char".

Comment: Ok. The function will modify the pointer next_token. So it needs to know the adress of next_token.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because `strtok_s()` maintains state by moving `next_token` along every time you call it.